# html strange display on internet explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have some html codes:

```
<html><body bgcolor="#C0C0C0" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0"> 

<table border="0"  bgcolor="#ffffff"  width="736" 
    cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bordercolor="#000080"> 
  <tr> 
    <td width="100%" align="center">
    <img src="pic.gif" border="0" height="173" width="736"> 
    </td>
  </tr>
</table> 
</bdy></html>
```

pic.gif size: 736*173

It displays same on Firefox, Safari, Chrome, Opera

But it displays different content on ie,6,7,8,9

There is a border line under the gif image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    <body style="background-color:#C0C0C0; margin:0px;"> 
        <table style="border:0px solid #000080; background-color:"#000080" margin:0px; padding:0px; width:736px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> 
            <tr> 
                <td style="text-align:center;">
                    <img src="pic.gif" style="width:736px; height:173px;" border="0" /"> 
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table> 
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure, but it could be this `</bdy>` in the last line.

Also, you set a `bordercolor="#000080"` on the `table`... but have `border="0"` as well, which may be affecting it.

Answer (score 1):

Changed as `<bdy>` `</body>` and see. Probably even won't work because there are 7 more validation errors.

Submit your html file to  [Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/) and fix the 7 validation errors. Then probably this will work on all browsers. In many cases this is the easiest way to catch errors in your html files.